# In css, when inline element contains inline replaced element

Tags: html, css, layout, inline

```
<div class="box">
  <span>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/127/300/200" alt="" />
  <span/>
</div>
```

[image: the height of span]

the img width is 300px and height is 200px

the img is a child element of span, i can't understand why the height of span is only 21px（not 200px or bigger than 200px）

---

i think i find the answer, thx everybody!

[Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#Computing_heights_and_margins)

> 10.6.1 Inline, non-replaced elements
>
> **The height of the content area should be based on the font**

Comment: what do you want to do and what is your css ?

Comment: span is by default an inline element , so image overflows, turn it to display: inline-block; and it will expand to the full height of its content.

Comment: you want a detailed explanation or a fix?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set image height and width and probably want span to display inline-block.

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
 }
 
 img {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
 }
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/127/300/200" alt="" />
  <span/>
</div>
```